# Scrapy does not crawl using curl command

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy project. I can run the spiders using the "scrapy crawl somespider" command. But, now I am trying to use scrapyd to crawl. When I run

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=crawlers -d spider=someproject
```

The output I get is

```
{"status": "ok", "jobid": "e0ace24c51bd11e28372079b5fff36ad"}
```

Now, when I check the

```
http://localhost:6800/jobs
```

I see that there are no pending jobs and only a finished job is present which ran for

```
0:00:00.457973 time.
```

What can be the problem?

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: I think the job was scheduled successfully and it finished very quickly. This means that the real question is why it finished so quickly.

Comment: Yes. So why does this happen? Though the spiders run good when ran with command 'scrapy crawl anyspider'.

Comment: Check the logs of the job

Comment: The log just has one line "2012-12-29 18:36:58+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.3 started (bot: SomeBot)"

Comment: I have no idea what might be wrong. What i would do - debug. Put some prints to follow were the code goes (i think ipdb/pdb might no work in case of `scrapy server`)